# My agents are producing too many children

Tags: netlogo

I'm working on a model where there is sexual reproduction of offspring, so there are two agent types, males and females. I ask the agents to reproduce once they reach a certain age: 400 ticks and continue to do so every 400th tick.

Females should only produce one child provided there are males. The model works for the first few generations but then the population explodes. With a starting population of one female and one male the numbers proceed as follows: 2, 3, 7, 19, 575. I don't know why it suddenly increases from 19 to 575.

It looks like some of the female offspring reproduce immediately after birth despite having an `age = 0` i.e. they're not following this command:

```
 ask females [
        if  age > 0 and age mod 400  = 0 [
      reproduce
        ]
```

Here's the full model:

```
turtles-own [age]

breed[males male]
breed[females female]

females-own [ mates max-mate-count mate-count availa-males mother father]


to setup
  clear-all

    crt 2 [
    ifelse random 2 = 1 [set breed males] [set breed females]
  ]
  ask females [set color grey
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

  ask males [set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

      reset-ticks
end

to go 

  ask turtles [increment-age]

  ask females [
    if  age > 0 and age mod 400  = 0 [
    choose-mates
  ]
  ]

 ask females [
    if  age > 0 and age mod 400  = 0 [
  reproduce
    ]
  ]


  tick
end

to increment-age
  set age (1 + age)
end

to choose-mates 

  ask females   [
    set mates males in-radius 100 with [age >= 400]
  ]
end


to reproduce 
    ask females with [count mates > 0 ]  [
    hatch 1  [
    set mother myself
    set father one-of [mates] of mother


      ifelse random 2 = 1 [set breed males
                          set color red
                        move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = black]
                        set age 0
                       ]

                        [set breed females
                         set color grey
                        move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = black]
                        set mate-count 0
                        set age 0

                        ]]]  
end
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: I do think this is a good question, but you get a +1 from me for the title alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't `ask females` in the `reproduce` proc.  See below.  I've made some other suggestions as well.

```
turtles-own [age]

breed[males male]
breed[females female]

females-own [ mates max-mate-count mate-count availa-males mother father]


to setup
  clear-all
  create-males 1 [init-male]
  create-females 1 [init-female]
  reset-ticks
end
to init
  set age 0
  move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = black]
  ifelse (breed = males) [init-male][init-female]
end
to init-male
  set color red
end
to init-female
  set color gray
  set mate-count 0
end

to-report fertile
  report (age > 0 and age mod 400  = 0)
end

to go 
  ask turtles [increment-age]
  let _fertile (females with [fertile])
  ask _fertile [choose-mates]
  ask _fertile [reproduce]
  tick
end

to increment-age
  set age (1 + age)
end

to choose-mates 
  ;ask females   [  ;DONT DO THIS!
    set mates (males in-radius 100 with [age >= 400])
  ;]
end


to reproduce ;female proc
  ;ask females with [count mates > 0 ]  [ ;DON'T DO THIS!!
  if (count mates > 0) [  ;DO THIS INSTEAD
    hatch 1  [
      set mother myself
      set father one-of [mates] of mother
      set breed one-of (list males females)
      init
    ]
  ]
end
```